# python program will not execute, there is no errors

Tags: python, class, google-chrome, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(selfself):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\pepe2\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://account.microsoft.com/account")
        driver.find_element_by_id("meControl").click()


    def test_Login(self):

        emailFieldID    = "email"
        passFieldID     = "pass"
        LoginButtonID   = "idSIButton9"

        emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID))
        passFieldElement  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(passFieldID))
        LoginButtonElement= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(LoginButtonID))

        emailFieldElement.clear().send_keys("************")
        passFieldElement.clear().send_keys("***********")
        LoginButtonElement.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


    if __name__ == '_main_':
        unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling this indirectly through a class, not in main. Hence,  `(__name__ == '_main_')` will always be False.

Answer (score -1):

Notice what happens when I run this code by itself.

```
if __name__ == '_main_':
    print ('something 1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('something 2')
```

The result is,

```
something 2
```

**There should be double underscores on either side of 'main'.**

---

I've changed this line:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\pepe2\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

(The path must be marked as a raw string because it contains backslashes.)

---

I suspect that the one line in the main program should be,

```
LoginTest.main()
```

because `LoginTest` derives from `unittest`. However, although the script now runs it throws an error claiming that `LoginTest` lacks the attribute `Main'.

**It's up to you now.**